# Starting jenkins build for local selenium test suit and getting weird chrome driver message

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have been trying to run my test suite with Jenkins and it was working previously, but now it seems as though it stalls out, because of the following

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch- 
heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 53894
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on 
keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch- 
heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 53897
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on 
keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch- 
heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 53896
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on 
keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch- 
heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 53895
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on 
keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

This is weird to me considering that I have chrome driver 93 installed not 92 and I have no idea what ports it is referring to... It looks like it keeps producing, so I have to manual stop the build.

Comment: Whatever you posted there is no error all that is information

Comment: Add the code where chrome driver is started. Are you on Linux?

Comment: @Jortega I am not on Linux.. I will add that code when I get back to my desk. I would also like to add when I run it from visual studio it runs fine, but from Jenkins gives me this